# for some reason i keep getting a unindent does not match any outer indentation level (i just started python)

Tags: python

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input().strip())
if n % 2:
    print('Weird')
  elif for n in range(2,5) and % 2 == 0:
     print(Not weird)
    elif if n % 2 == 0 and for n in range(6,20):
      print(weird)
       elif if n % 2 == 0 and n > 20:
        print('not weird')
```

Comment: Why are all the `elif` blocks staggered like that?

Comment: Is your real code indented like the one you provide ?

Comment: Your indentation is just completely wrong. Check out some Python tutorials.

Comment: Are you aware that Python uses indentation to mark blocks of statements? Subsequently, that parts of the same statement, such as ``if``, ``elif``, ``else``, must have the same indentation?

Comment: And it's not `elif if` – "elif" is a contraction of "else if".

Comment: And also, what does `elif for` supposed to do?

Comment: Also note that `range`s are half-open, as is common in programming. `range(a, b)` includes `a`, but not `b`.

Answer (score 0):

`if` and `elif` in python should follow the same indentation level. Also, you are not supposed to use `for` in `elif` like that. Here's the corrected code-

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  n = int(input().strip())
  if n % 2:
    print('Weird')
  elif n in range(2,5) and n % 2 == 0:
    print('Not weird')
  elif n % 2 == 0 and n in range(6,20):
    print('weird')
  elif n % 2 == 0 and n > 20:
    print('not weird')
```